# How do I press "Enter" button after the password is passed through command-line?

Tags: python, pexpect

I used the following code, which runs the command and prompts password. When I entered the password using sendline, for some reason the login is not happening.

How to debug this and ensure the "Enter" button is sent?

Code:

```
    child = pexpect.spawn('tool --server=commander.company.com login username',logfile=sys.stdout)
    child.expect('Password:')
    child.sendline('com0201')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendline()` will automatically send the new line character defined in `os.linesep`, so you shouldn't need to do anything special to send the "enter button".

You have logging enabled; what output do you see?

Something else to try is to `child.interact()` after you send the password. This will let you interact with the child process and might provide some clue if there is a problem.

Comment: how to enable logging?how to use child.interact?

Comment: Logging is enabled via the `logfile` keyword argument that is being passed into `pexpect.spawn`. Add a call to `child.interact()` after sending the password.